# How do I write 'android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"' in code?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I do it with Java code instead of XML? Thanks

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : You cannot.

Long answer : it is not possible out of the box, I guess you could disassemble the Activity class and study the code, and rewrite it in a sublclass, but I believe that you will get more trouble than you will solve.